# Return count of value based on ID and list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have three dataframes. `df1` is used to summarize information based on `df2` and `df3` as follows:

For every `ID` in `df2`, I want to count how many times it has a `Value` from `df3` and return the count in the `Result` column of `df1`.

df1

```
ID  Result
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   1
6   2
8   0
10  1
```

df2

```
ID  Value
1   A
1   A
1   F
2   B
2   C
3   D
3   D
4   C
5   A
6   A
6   B
7   C
7   D
8   E
8   F
8   G
9   A
9   B
9   C
10  D
```

df3

```
ValueList
A
B
C
D
```

I tried to filter the rows based on `df3` using `isin`, but this only returned some rows and some whose values were not in `df3`

`df = df2[df2['Value'].isin(df3['Value'])].drop(['Value'], axis = 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler way is to sum up the boolean `isin` Series grouped by ID:

```
In [11]: df2['Value'].isin(df3['ValueList']).groupby(df2["ID"]).sum()
Out[11]:
ID
1     2.0
2     2.0
3     2.0
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     2.0
7     2.0
8     0.0
9     3.0
10    1.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

*Note: You can use `.sum(type='int64')` to ensure it's int dtype.*